# How to programmatically set up a dynamic number of collection views in Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a list of many `Decks`, which is mainly has a `name` and a list of `Cards`. The below shows the class structure.

```
class Deck{
    var id:String
    var name:String
    var cards:[Card]

    init(id:String, name:String, cards:[Card]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.cards = cards
    }
}

class Card {
    var id:String
    var name:String

    init(id:String, name:String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I need to be able to create a single `UICollectionView` for each deck, where each cell should represent a button with the single card's name, and I need to be able to identify which cell's button is tapped. This means that I need to allow both dynamic number of **UICollectionView**(list of decks) and a dynamic number of **UICollectionViewCell**(list of cards). Please note that I already understand how to create the cells dynamically and identify which cell's buttons are tapped.

Overall, the main issue lies in the fact that I won't know how many decks and hence how many UICollectionViews I have to create. But, since the structure across all UICollectionViews are the same but populated with different values (i.e number of cells, cell's label title has different values), I am wondering what is the way to dynamically create UICollectionViews (**NOT UICollectionViewCells**) and populate them with decks from a list like *decks:[Deck]*

Thanks a bunch! The image at the bottom shows roughly what I would like to do.

[image]

Comment: could you show a visual example of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: added a photo to better illustrate!

Comment: so the sections are based on decks and then those decks have cards. So from what I understand you'll need to use a collection view whose cells a have collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not clear if you really need a collection of UICollectionView objects or you could do with multiple sections in the same collection view. Anyhow, if you do like multiple collection views just make a collection or table view displaying decks list and put collection view for the deck in the cell.

```
class DeckCell: UICollectionViewCell { // or class DeckCell: UITableViewCell
    var deck: Deck = .empty

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension DeckCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.deck.cards.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.card = self.deck.cards[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the response closest to what I need. If I understand you correctly here, this approach means that I should have a nested collectionView? One where each cell represents each deck, and within each cell there is another collection view with cells representing each card?

Comment: @ChiahSoon this is the usual approach when you need a dynamic list of collection views prior to iOS 13. If you only need iOS 13 you may also look at UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout or maybe you can just use multiple sections in collection view with a section for each deck.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for the valuable advice, this will be my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You already have an solution you have a list in which you have a items so you have to implement dynamically so you just need to count a number of item's in a list.

So for do that you use items.count in to func:-

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your Cell Identifier Name", for: indexPath)
    // This will return a each item name from the item list and display in to a cell
    cell.textLabel.text = item[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Here you write a code when user select a particular cell
}
```

Comment: I believe this code is useful only for a single UICollectionView (i.e dynamic cells only, not dynamic UICollectionView s). I have added more information to illustrate the issue, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution for you.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //number of items in Decks Array will be its count
    if collectionView == dockCollectionView {
        return Decks.count  //It will tell the collection view how much cell will be there
    }
    if collectionView == cardsCollectionView {
        return Cards.count
    }
}

//Setup your resuable cell here
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //Setup for Dock CollectionView
    if collectionView == dockCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your Dock Cell Identifier Name", for: indexPath)
        // This will return a each item name from the item list and display in to a cell
        cell.textLabel.text = Decks[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
    //Setup for Cards CollectionView
    if collectionView == cardsCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Your Cards Cell Identifier Name", for: indexPath)
        // This will return a each item name from the item list and display in to a cell
        cell.textLabel.text = Cards[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}

//Now get to know which cell is tapped
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == dockCollectionView {
        print(Decks[indexPath.row].name)
    }
    if collectionView == cardsCollectionView {
        print(Cards[indexPath.row].name)
    }
    // Here you write a code when user select a particular cell
}
```

Comment: Same as the above, this code is useful only for a single UICollectionView. I have added more information to illustrate the issue. Please let me know if I am wrong on this!

Comment: @ChiahSoon I just update the code, you can set multiple `collectionView` within same delegates.

Comment: I think I should clarify that each collection view should represent a deck itself, and the cells are the cards. Thus there should be multiple UICollectionView, all of which are identical(UICollectionViewCells are identical too) in structure, but with different values (number of cells, cell label title, etc) corresponding to each deck. Also,  the main issue that I am facing is that I don't know how many UICollectionView should be created because I won't know how many decks are available to the user. I appreciate the effort and I've updated my question to be informative!